# problems with vue-cli for production

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, vue-cli

I am currently working on a vue-cli app,but I am having problems to run the app on production locally. After finishing everything on the dev environment I used the following command to build my production version of the app.

```
npm run build
```

the following is my config/prod.env.js file:

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"'
}
```

config/index.js file:

```
'use strict'
// Template version: 1.3.1
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  dev: {

    // Paths
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},

    // Various Dev Server settings
    host: 'localhost', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
    port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one will be determined
    autoOpenBrowser: false,
    errorOverlay: true,
    notifyOnErrors: true,
    poll: false, // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-watchoptions-


    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#development
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    // If you have problems debugging vue-files in devtools,
    // set this to false - it *may* help
    // https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/options.html#cachebusting
    cacheBusting: true,

    cssSourceMap: true
  },

  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',

    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    productionSourceMap: true,
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  }
}
```

config/dev.env.js:

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"'
})
```

build/build.js:

```
'use strict'
require('./check-versions')()

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

const ora = require('ora')
const rm = require('rimraf')
const path = require('path')
const chalk = require('chalk')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

const spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, (err, stats) => {
    spinner.stop()
    if (err) throw err
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false, // if you are using ts-loader, setting this to true will make typescript errors show up during build
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n')

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
      console.log(chalk.red('  Build failed with errors.\n'))
      process.exit(1)
    }

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
})
```

it created a dist folder in which I initialised a package.json and installed express on it:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project_gorilla_production",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "THe production version for project gorilla",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ProjectGorilla",
    "BkChatLDN",
    "zezemills"
  ],
  "author": "Christopher Salay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, function(){
    console.log('Your node js server is running');
})
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>project_gorilla</title><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js></script><link href=/static/css/app.b2785d7282208bedd7a467d4d7584204.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.91dc1c7d90da0f3312fd.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.75194bcb7c3977e313be.js></script></body></html>
```

I get the following error when I run node server.js:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/static/css/app.b2785d7282208bedd7a467d4d7584204.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

and a lot of my files such as the manifest, the vendor and the app js files gives of a 404 error.

Comment: can you show your **.env file**?

Comment: @AsifSharifShahid I have added some relevant files, I am using the vu-cli webpack template. IF there are any other files you would need please let me know.